# What does "Comp." at the end of a posuk's translation mean?

Tags: rambam, translation, english

I.e. 201 results for Comp. here: http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Guide_for_the_Perplexed_(Friedlander)/Part_III/Chapters#CHAPTER_XLVI

I assume it means "end of verse" or something?

Comment: I would assume it means line break, but I have no idea.  Seems like it's something that was added into the file.

Comment: It's actually at the beginning of the Pasuk. I don't know what it means. I agree with @avi, that it looks like it was added by the computer code rather than the translator.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: @SethJ The physical book has it also.

Comment: @Alex weird. I don't remember this question at all.

Comment: @SethJ Well it is from six years ago....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems in your example that the "Comp." comes before the verse and that it means "compared to."

Comment: as in "v'chen" brought to bring scriptural proof to a previous statement.

Comment: It's a little odd, though, in that the usual scholarly abbreviation for this purpose would be the Latinate *cf.*